# Nginx forward all requests to another domain

Tags: nginx

I have been struggling to get this whole setup to work. I've found bits and pieces on the net but nothing that solves all of my requirements. I need to do this to make IE8 work, so unfortunately my hands are tied a little. I can move some endpoints around, but probably not too much.

I have a users api which sits at `https://api.foo.com/1.0/users`. That endpoint accepts all request types along with parameters, and dynamic segments. Below are some samples

- GET   https://awesome.foo.com/1.0/users
- GET   https://awesome.foo.com/1.0/users?a=b
- GET   https://awesome.foo.com/1.0/users/1?a=b
- POST  https://awesome.foo.com/1.0/users
- PATCH https://awesome.foo.com/1.0/users/1

I want to configure nginx to accept requests from another domain and path and seamlessly forward them to those endpoints. For example

- GET http://example.com/api/awesome/users -> https://awesome.foo.com/1.0/users
- GET http://example.com/api/awesome/users?a=b -> https://awesome.foo.com/1.0/users?a=b
- GET http://example.com/api/awesome/users/1?a=b -> https://awesome.foo.com/1.0/users/1?1=b
- POST http://example.com/api/awesome/users -> https://awesome.foo.com/1.0/users
- PATCH http://example.com/api/awesome/users/1 -> https://awesome.foo.com/1.0/users/1

In order to accomplish this, I need request parameters as well as form data to be forwarded. Basically the whole request needs to be forwarded in tact and then return. Also note that I have a couple of different subdomains so `awesome` is but one of a couple of names I want to change.

The pattern is this

```
http://example.com/api/<subdomain>/<details> -> https://<subdomain>.foo.com/1.0/<details>
```

My biggest struggle is keeping the  exactly the same, along with passing different kinds of requests.

**my efforts**
I've tried a number of things, but probably the closest I've got to is this

```
location ~ ^/api/(.*)/(*.) { 
    resolver 8.8.8.8;
    proxy_pass https://$1.foo.com/1.0/$2$is_args$args;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    #proxy_set_header X-Host $host;
}

**The `X-Host` directive doesn't work for me hence the comment
```

This works for the first two cases, but not the third. Also, I haven't got the POST request to work with this. Mostly I get `502 Bad Gateway` errors. It seems to me that the  doesn't map completely instead it cuts off at the first '/' it receives. Adding another location directive with 3 regex params also hasn't helped me.

I'd really appreciate any help on this topic as I'm totally stuck as to what to do next.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex is incorrect, you sould use `location ~ ^/api/([^/]+)/(.*)$` instead because I don't see how the PCRE lib can choose $1 as the subdomain, its content will likely be `awesome/users` instead of `awesome`.

Comment: Awesome. Its days like today when I realise I need to drastically up my regex knowledge.

Comment: an aside, the last part should be `(.*)$` not `(*.)$`

Comment: @Gevious yep, typo here. I think, you got the idea :)